# Optimal equation for combining 2 parameters to make prediction

Tags: optimization

I have a binary classification (true or false). I also have two parameters (A and B). I want to combine A and B in to one equation. Then, based on the output of this equation, I want to be able to classify as true or false. So basically come up with an equation then a threshold or cut off.

1. Come up with optimal equation which is a function of both A and B.
2. Identify threshold or cutoff value which allows me to correctly classify as true or false based on the output from the equation.

This is a table of my data:
[image]

Any ideas/help/suggestions are appreciated. Please (correctly) assume that my level is low.

Update: Thank you for comments. I am sorry for only pasting an image. Data is provided here so that it can be copy and pasted (as comma separated).

A =

5682.495356,4429.223539,577.0245893,4021.798511,2656.508253,3852.19895,2891.631157,1920.30827,1436.108417,2971.991015,1799.685753,2868.907574,5012.535722,158.127461,4314.723152,295.7375117,99.55356372,208.759135,258.89442,201.8096896,275.7164903,147.2620582,280.5700713,432.6305561,186.7525578,407.5904908,391.2648094,150.4610093,128.1786604,163.4222766,259.8320436,308.5884704,320.0605708,120.0709741,258.563494,256.7434012,208.5385177,255.8057776

B =

2583.20815,1815.95628,1883.465179,1515.916731,3775.975667,2313.338018,2657.61134,3328.232825,3218.475711,2350.125956,3096.364026,3277.215071,88.30208062,273.1793912,2485.640142,1540.515561,1038.059625,400.0895021,2531.307926,1008.993293,709.8362134,1113.179821,845.0746279,1263.365059,1008.496905,1141.087911,1631.740821,1139.984825,964.7595217,743.9215886,900.1186482,1120.460192,1281.510833,399.8137304,2065.03323,1327.34408,1315.87198,476.6437106

Flag =

1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

Comment: Hi! Have you tried running a logistic regression on it?

Comment: It might be helpful to provide the data in a text (i.e. copy-paste-able) form, so that one can play around with the data set. (rather than as an image.)

Comment: Thank u Fede for the sugegstion. i have not. i will look in 2 this

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. If your points which satisfy your condition (i.e. are classified as 1) are $(x_i, y_i)$ then
$$
f(x,y) = \prod_{i=1}^n ((x-x_i)^2 + (y-y_i)^2)
$$
This function is equal to zero iff $(x,y)$ are classified as 1.